# Некорректно обрабатывается SQL запрос SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Я использую Node.js, делаю запрос к моей базе данных SQLite:

```
db.serialize(() => {
    db.run('INSERT INTO users (text) VALUES ('+ data +')')
})
```

data это значение из input type="text".
Если там цифры то все работает корректно, но если там текст, я получаю ошибку:

> no such column: blabla Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
> ] {   errno: 1,   code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }

Почему то происходит поиск столбца под названием *data* но ведь я его указал в VALUES! Почему так происходит?

Comment: `db.run(\`INSERT INTO users (text) VALUES ('${data}')\`)` _Если там цифры то все работает корректно, но если там число_ - а как вы цифры и числа отличаете? ) _Почему то происходит поиск столбца под названием data но ведь я его указал в VALUES! Почему так происходит?_ - пому что значение надо в кавычках вставлять

Comment: @InDevX Заговорился, исправил опечатку. Я имел ввиду текст.

Comment: На сайте есть примеры и описание https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/insert/ В Вашем случае db.serialize не нужен, достаточно db.run. И ещё можно в base64 перекодировать data. чтобы там кавычек не было. Нельзя просто так вставлять в инсерт текст - это дырка для бэк дора

Comment: @Виктор, Да, я знаю про SQL инъекции. Но пока что я оставляю эту тему на потом. В водимом мною тексте нету никаких кавычек.

Comment: @Виктор Спасибо, уже GPT подсказал, в ссылке инфа тоже верная. Использовал

db.run('INSERT INTO users (text) VALUES (?)', [data])

Comment: Какой текст внутри `data`? Покажите его нам. Там внутри явно какие-то управляющие символы: кавычки, запятые...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А вот и нет, нету там никаких кавычек и подобного, там обычный текст, будь хоть одна буква, кириллица, латиница

Answer (score 0):

```
db.run('INSERT INTO users (text) VALUES (?)', [data])
```

Данный код корректно работает. Третьим параметром может быть передана функция обрабатывающая ошибки.

Тем не менее, я все еще не понимаю почему это работает именно так, и почему мой старый код не работал...
Если кто объяснит буду премного благодарен!